# Android: Layout object with integer in ID cannot be referenced

Tags: android, xml, layout, integer

I'm trying to set the images of some ImageButtons in my layout programmatically. 
To do so, I named my ImageButtons ic_1 to ic_5.

During my initialization method, I want to loop through these 5 ImageButtons and set their images according to a list of possible icons.
Basically users can change the order in which the icons should be shown, which in turn would change the image on the ImageButtons.

However, i can't seem to reference the buttons since they have an Integer in their ID.
The code I use for this is as such:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

                    String butid = "ic_"+i;
                    int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(butid, "id",
                            getPackageName());
                    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
```

However, this returns a NullPointerException as `resID` returns 0. When I just use "ic_1" in `butid`, it also returns 0.
However if I give an ImageButton an ID as ic_one, it does work. But if I'm going to use pure-text id's, I won't be able to loop through the ImageButtons.

First I thought this meant the ID's werent properly translated into the R.java file, but the buttons are present in it, with their respective id's as shown below.

```
    public static final int ic_1=0x7f05000e;
    public static final int ic_2=0x7f05000f;
```

Does anyone know if it's seriously not possible to use an int in the ID of a layout object, and if so, if it's possible to loop through the ImageButtons like I want without the need of an integer in the ID? A simple example would be appreciated.

---

Some more info for Warren:

Layout specification:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    setMenuImage();
    initMainScreen();
}
```

Full code that should change the icons:

```
public void initMainScreen() {
    if (standard == false) {
        retrieveLinks();
        int size = mso.getHome().getIcon().size();

        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

                String butid = "ic_"+i;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(butid, "id",
                        getPackageName());

                String buttype = mso.getHome().getIcon().get(i)
                        .getIconName();
                System.out.println(buttype.toLowerCase());
                int typeID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttype.toLowerCase(),
                        "drawable", getPackageName());

                ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(resID);
                if(button != null){
                button.setImageResource(typeID);
                }else{
                    System.out.println(butid+" "+resID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Specification in the layout file: (same goes for all buttons)

```
    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="33" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/empty_icon" android:onClick="iconClick" android:background="@null" android:id="@+id/ic_1"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be exactly what you were trying to do, but if you are only dealing with 5 buttons, you could always just declare a static array of the the Button Id's and loop through them.

Something like:

```
private static final int[] buttons =
     {R.id.ic_1, R.id.ic_2, R.id.ic_3, R.id.ic_4, R.id.ic_5};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);
    setMenuImage();
    initMainScreen();
}

public void initMainScreen() {
    if (standard == false) {
        retrieveLinks();
        int size = mso.getHome().getIcon().size();

        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

                String buttype = mso.getHome().getIcon().get(i)
                        .getIconName();
                System.out.println(buttype.toLowerCase());
                int typeID = getResources().getIdentifier(
                        buttype.toLowerCase(), "drawable", getPackageName());

                //Using the array of button id's directly
                ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(buttons[i]);
                if(button != null){
                button.setImageResource(typeID);
                }else{
                    System.out.println(butid+" "+resID);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a much better approach.

Comment: Yeah I had this in mind as my backup plan in case I really can't find a fix for my problem, but it would be nice to find a proper fix instead so I can keep it in mind for future usages.

Also, the amount of buttons might go up to 30+ in the future and I'm not really looking forward to making a static array all the time. However I might end up going with this answer, since it does seem like the better approach.

Comment: Ended up going with your answer since my search for a better answer has not revealed anything usefull.
Your method works like a charm though! But I still find it weird that it won't work using my method.

Answer (score 2):

you are starting with 0, that is the problem.

start the loop from  `i =1 ;`

Comment: My mistake actually, I messed around a bit before posting here. The original loop did have 1 instead of 0, but that didn't work either.

Checked again just to be sure, but `int i = 1;` doesn't do the trick either. Even added a `println` to make sure the string is actually `ic_1` (it is), but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You start your loop with `i = 0` but your `ic_1` starts with `1`. Change the loop to start with `1`, that should do the trick.

Comment: My mistake actually, I messed around a bit before posting here. The original loop did have 1 instead of 0, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show us how you specify the layout that should be used?

Comment: Added more info in the opening post. Hopefully that will make things clearer.