# Android display images dynamically

Tags: android, imageview

I have a bunch of images named, 1.jpg, 2.jpg… and 56.jpg. I also have an _id value in a variable dependent on which item was selected from the previous list activity. I have the following code to display an image.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headerimage);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

What I would like to do is dynamically display the image that corresponds with the _id value, e.g.. something like this?

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.headerimage);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myID + ".jpg");
```

How do I do that?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Just use [Resouces.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Be aware that **this implementation is slower** that using the id and **always check if the resourceId is not 0** (that would mean the resource you asked for doesn't exit.

Example:

```
 View view = //...
 int number = //...      
 int resId = getIdentifier("files_"+number, "drawable", "com.my.project.package");
 view.setBackgroundResource(resId);
```

Comment: Thanks Pedro, it worked perfectly! and Sander, your example would have worked two and I love the lateral thinking but I have 150 images. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't. I had a similar problem a while ago, you can find it [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890277/android-layout-object-with-integer-in-id-cannot-be-referenced)
For some reason, Android doesn't seem to like it if you try to reference resource names dynamically. I eventually fixed it by putting all the resources that I dynamically wanted to reference in an Array.